# How to interact with a python file's objects methods (putting inputs, alterting data, and getting outputs ) from the command line?

Tags: python, shell, command-line-interface

Say that this is my python program

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function


class Concat_Class():
    def __init__(self, cache=False):
        self.cats = []

    def GET_Answers(self, questionList, context):
        for question in questionList:
            self.cats.append(question + context )
        return self.answers

class Interface_Class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.questionList = []
        self.answers = []
        self.catObj = Concat_Class()

    def POST_Question(self, question):
        self.questionList.append(question)

    def PUT_Question(self, index, question):
        self.questionList[index] = question

    def PUT_Conext(self, context):
        self.context = context

    def GET_Answers(self):
        answers = self.modelObj.GET_Answers(self.questionList, self.context)
        print(answers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    interface_Object = Interface_Class()
```

Which I save to a file called `testProgram.py`

How would I interact with `interface_Object`, calling its methods, passing arguments to those methods, etc

Edit:

I don't want to do an one time interact at the beginning. I wast to continuously update the values.

Comment: Call it with `python -i testProgram.py`, and you'll stay in the Python REPL after the script finishes executing.  You can then type things like `interface_Object.GET_Answers()` to interactively try it out.

Comment: If you want to pass arguments into python scripts run from the command line, I think argparse is the module you want: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html The docs are kind of opaque though, I'd look for some other material to assist.

Comment: [argparse?](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html)